# How do I disable powerline-shell only for the VSCode terminal?

Tags: command-line, powerline-plugin

I have installed powerline-shell for my terminal and it works fine.

However, the terminal in VSCode always starts with the error shown in the image below, and I can't see my Git status or my current directory when using the terminal:

[image]

I tried playing around with the terminal settings in VSCode but nothing seems to have an effect on this. Other than experimenting, I am not sure how should I go about solving this. How can I disable powerline-shell when I'm using the terminal in VSCode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a few lines of code in my `.bashrc` to detect if the terminal was called from VSCode or not and only start powerline if it was not as follows:

```
if [[ "$TERM_PROGRAM" != "vscode" ]]; then
   # use powerline
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

*This helped for me:*
run `python -m pip install powerline-shell` in terminal in VSCode.